# Internet Explorer 8 not allowing dynamic creation of button

Tags: javascript, html, css

Internet explorer is showing error when im trying to create button dynamically. Whereas it is working fine in firefox

```
var deleteButton = document.createElement('input');
 ratingSliderContainer.appendChild(deleteButton);
 deleteButton.setAttribute('type','button');
 deleteButton.setAttribute('value','delete');
```

It is showing error at third line

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't modify the `type` of an input once it's been added to the DOM. Try re-ordering your statements like so:

```
var deleteButton = document.createElement('input');
deleteButton.setAttribute('type','button');
deleteButton.setAttribute('value','delete');
ratingSliderContainer.appendChild(deleteButton);
```